# Output an array as PHP eval-able code

Tags: php, arrays, eval

Basically I want some function like `array_as_php` which is essentially the inverse of `eval`:

```
$array = array( '1' => 'b', '2' => 'c' );
echo array_as_php($array);
```

will print the following `eval`-able string:

```
array( '1' => 'b', '2' => 'c' )
```

Comment: What are you planning on using this for?

Comment: Did you mean `array ('1' => 'b', '2' => 'c' );` instead of `array( '1': 'b', '2': 'c' );`?

Comment: is there a reason print_r won't work?

Comment: @madmik3: it is. `print_r` results are not evalable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[var_export()](http://php.net/var_export) is what you are looking for.

```
$array = array ('1' => 'b', '2' => 'c' );
echo var_export($array, true);
```